# How to extract page category and variable names into array from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, google-tag-manager

I have a link like this:

> https://example.com/category?variable1=value1&variable2=value2

and I need to extract page category and variable names and save it into variable and into array of variable names:

```
category = "category";
array = ["variable1", "variable2"];
```

Any sugestions how can I achieve it using Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If your link is a string like the one you reported a simple solution can be based on:

- [str.split([separator[, limit]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) where as separator you can use a regex
- [array.splice(start, deleteCount)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in order to remove the first and last ele

The example:

```js
var str = 'https://example.com/category?variable1=value1&variable2=value2';
var res = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split(/[?]|=[^&]*&{0,1}/);
var category = res[0];
var arr = res.splice(1, res.length - 2);


console.log(category);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If an object works for you as well here is a solution:

```js
//Get variables into an object
function uriToJson (url) {
 const regx = /(\?|&)([^=]+)=([^&]+)/g;
 const index = url.search(regx) + 1;
 const params = url.substring(index);

  return JSON.parse(`{"${decodeURI(params)
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
    .replace(/&/g, '","')
    .replace(/=/g, '":"')}"}`);
}

const url = 'https://example.com/category?variable1=value1&variable2=value2'; //window.location.href...

const obj = uriToJson(url);

console.log(obj);

//Get category into a variable

var stepone = url.substring(0,url.indexOf('?'));
var steptwo = stepone.substring(stepone.indexOf('m/') + 1 )
var category = steptwo.replace('/','');
console.log(category);
```